# Java applets freezes browser

Tags: mac, macos, java

Java applets freezes every browser (Chrome, Safari, Firefox).

**Java version:** 1.6.0_33

**Software:** OS X 10.8.1 (12B19)

"Native" Java applications (like Eclipse etc.) works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably well understand it is likely to be a Java issue.

Unless there is a particular reason you want to use that version of Java you should get the latest Java version.

Download here:

http://www.java.com/en/download/index.jsp

Comment: Apple Software Update has just offered me Java 1.6.0_35.